# Latex Beamer problem

Tags: latex, beamer

I am preparing a Beamer slide with two simple equations. I wanna include
this in a block as shown below.

```
\begin{block}{Equation}
\begin{align*}
r &= a + b \\
s &= c + d
\end{align*}
\end{block}
```

It looks alright, the only problem is that it wastes so much space above and below the
equations. I tried vspace{-2cm} but it did not have any effect. Any other idea how I could
reduce the empty area above and below the equations. Might it be possible that the block size is fixed and thats the problem why it takes so much space?

Many thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Setting `\abovedisplayskip=0pt` fixes the problem.

```
\begin{block}{Equation}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt
\begin{align*}
r &= a + b \\
s &= c + d
\end{align*}
\end{block}
```

Sources: [One](http://old.nabble.com/bad-spacing-when-using-math-environment-%28align,-gather%29-within-a-block-td20035154.html)

Answer (score 1):

Actually this is not a problem and moreover its the right way to do it. Beamer does not waste that space -- it simply centers everything vertically. Put something underneath and the equation will go higher. If you don't want to put anything below then you simply don't need that space. In that case it's better to center everything so it was symmetric and therefore more pleasing to the eye.